# How to add/Modify Redux Framework options in Child Theme

Tags: wordpress

I am using a paid theme which is using Redux Framework. I am trying to add a new field in Footer Options. I am able to add this field in options but only in print_r() function it is showing not showing in Themes Options Panel.

```
function add_another_section_bl($sections){

$sections[12]['fields'][] = array(
    'id'        => 'rd_footer_message_1',
    'type'      => 'textarea',
    'title'     => __('Text 2 to display in footer under bar', 'thefoxwp'),
    'subtitle'  => __('write your copyright information or anything you\'d like.', 'thefoxwp'),
    'validate'  => 'html', //see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post
    'default'   => 'Copyright 2015 <a href="http://themeforest.net/user/tranmautritam?ref=tranmautritam" target="_blank">Tranmautritam\'s team</a>   |   All Rights Reserved'
);
return $sections;}

add_filter("redux/options/rd_data/register", 'add_another_section_bl');
```

In array data it is showing the required data but not in Options Panel in wordpress dashboard.

Kindly get me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler approach if you use the Redux API:
https://docs.redux.io/configuration/redux-api.html

You can modify, add, update any section or field before it is rendered. Please note, you may have to put your code within hooks. Also please note the Redux 4 method names have changed from setArgs to set_args (camelcase to non).

Otherwise, you will have all you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Should I overwrite all options in child theme or just required addition in the option?

Comment: One more thing to know, how can I get reference in child theme for **Redux::**

Comment: I have tried this one but it is not working in **Child Theme**:


`if ( ! class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) {
    return;
}
$opt_name = 'rd_data';
$args = Array(
    'opt_name'    => $opt_name,
    'customizer'  => true
);

Redux::set_args ( $opt_name, $args );

$args = Redux::get_args( $opt_name );
print_r($args);
echo Redux::get_arg( $opt_name, 'opt_name' );`

Comment: I've included this one `require_once get_template_directory() . '/admin/redux-framework/inc/class.redux_api.php';`

Comment: After including this I am calling this one: `$section = Redux::getSection( 'rd_data', 'general-settings' );` this shows nothing a black page in `print_r($section);`

Comment: So if you're not using Redux 4, I'd suggest you do setArgs. ;)

You have to get the proper opt_name, and you have to run it AFTER the hook they're using. So if you wrapped your code in the add_action('init', 'myfunction', 0) you'd have all the values you seek.  ;)

Just make sure the opt_name is correct.

Comment: Could you please send me the exact code? so that it will be easy for me to implement it. I have tried a lot but still not succeeded.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I don't get on here all the time.  ;)

Comment: Its okay. Your guide was really helpful for me to solve the issue.